# Copiar arquivos em lote, renomeando-os com o nome do diretório original

Tags: bash, terminal

Suponha que eu tenho uma estrutura de diretórios organizados da seguinte maneira em meu PC:

```
Diretorio 01
  Arquivo 01.jpg
  Arquivo 02.jpg
  Arquivo 03.jpg
  Arquivo 04.jpg
Diretorio 02
  Arquivo 01.jpg
  Arquivo 02.jpg
Diretorio 03
  Arquivo 01.jpg
  Arquivo 02.jpg
  Arquivo 03.jpg
...
Diretorio n
  Arquivo 01.jpg
  Arquivo 02.jpg
  Arquivo 03.jpg
  Arquivo 04.jpg
```

São `n` diretórios diferentes. Dentro de cada um deles eu tenho um número variável de arquivos .jpg. Eu gostaria de copiar estes arquivos .jpg para outra pasta em meu computador, colocando-os todos no mesmo local e renomeando-os da seguinte maneira no processo:

```
Diretorio 01 Arquivo 01.jpg
Diretorio 01 Arquivo 02.jpg
Diretorio 01 Arquivo 03.jpg
Diretorio 01 Arquivo 04.jpg
Diretorio 02 Arquivo 01.jpg
Diretorio 02 Arquivo 02.jpg
Diretorio 03 Arquivo 01.jpg
Diretorio 03 Arquivo 02.jpg
Diretorio 03 Arquivo 03.jpg
...
Diretorio n Arquivo 01.jpg
Diretorio n Arquivo 02.jpg
Diretorio n Arquivo 03.jpg
Diretorio n Arquivo 04.jpg
```

Ou seja, cada arquivo resultante será nomeado de acordo com o diretório de origem e o nome original do arquivo. Note que os nomes dos arquivos se repetem dentro dos diretórios de origem.

Originalmente meus arquivos tem espaços nos nomes, mas este espaço não necessita estar presente no resultado final. Isto é, os nomes podem ser algo na linha `Diretorio_01_Arquivo_01.jpg` se isto tornar o algoritmo mais fácil de ser implementado.

Comment: Só uma pergunta, o nome dos diretorios podem ser aleatorios, só sendo seguidos do numero? Pode ser algo como `Foo 01`, `Bar 100`, etc?

Comment: Na verdade os nomes dos diretórios são aleatórios, mas sem os números. Os diretórios tem nomes de pessoas, tipo `Joao da Silva`, `Maria Oliveira`, `Jose de Souza` e assim por diante.

Comment: Então é só concatenar o nome do diretorio com o da foto ao mover o arquivo para a pasta de destino, então uma função recursiva simples resolve, vou tentar fazer uma resposta :)

Comment: Caro Marcus, revisei o código da resposta, tinha alguns problemas, mas agora creio que esteja funcionando bem, por experimentar e me avise qualquer falha que encontrar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que os nomes sejam aleatórios, tanto das pastas quanto dos arquivos, o que bastará será uma função recursiva para pegar a fotos, usar o `cp` e copiar para um novo destino, algo como

- `/home/docs/pasta/foo.jpg` ➡️ `/home/target/pasta_foo.jpg`

A "função" dentro do bash poderia ficar algo como `move_recursive`, então com o comando `cp` irá mover o arquivo para o destino desejado (você pode trocar por `mv` se desejar mover de vez, o que não recomendo pois o script não foi 100% testado), então isto:

```
echo "cp \"$file\" \"${destination_path}${only_dirname}_${only_filename}\""
```

Deverá ser isto:

```
cp "$file" "${destination_path}${only_dirname}_${only_filename}"
```

Ou isto:

```
mv "$file" "${destination_path}${only_dirname}_${only_filename}"
```

Note que usei `${...}` para poder trabalhar com o underline, pois se fizesse isso `$only_dirname_$only_filename` iria falhar.

> Eu coloquei em um `echo` o comando `cp` para evitar de executar sem ter certeza que funcionou, olhe o resultado de todos comando e saberá se esta executando corretamente

Para pegar apenas o nome do arquivo ou pasta usei:

```
$(basename $current_path)
```

O script todo deve ficar assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

# "função" para recursividade
move_recursive() {
    echo ""
    echo "-------------------------"
    echo "Lendo pasta: $path"
    echo "-------------------------"

    current_path="$1"

    for file in "$1"/*
    do
        if [ -d "$file" ]
        then
            move_recursive "$file"
        elif [ -f "$file" ]
        then
            only_dirname=$(basename $current_path)
            only_filename=$(basename "$file")

            # tire do echo para executar
            echo "cp \"$file\" \"${destination_path}${only_dirname}_${only_filename}\""
        fi
    done
}

# pasta de destino (troque pela pasta de destino, caminho completo)
destination_path="/home/destination/"

# pasta aonde estão as fotos (troque pelo caminho completo desejado)
source_path="/home/bar/"

move_recursive $source_path
```

---

### Trocando espaços em branco por underline/underscore com bash

Eu não consegui testar porque meu sistema não é unix-like, então não posso afirmar se funciona, mas creio que se usar desta forma:

```
echo "cp \"$file\" \"${destination_path}${only_dirname//[[:blank:]]/_}_${only_filename//[[:blank:]]/_}\""
```

Todos espaços serão trocados por `_`, em um exemplo prático, seria isto:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo="a b c d"

echo ${foo//[[:blank:]]/_}
```

Sendo `[[:blank:]]` a expressão regular para espaços em branco (TABs também) e após o `/` seria o caractere que irá substituir.

Comment: A função funcionou perfeitamente. Gostei da ideia de usar `echo` pra mostrar os comandos que serão executados. Nunca tinha visto isso antes.